# Join on PortSet's in CCR

Tags: ccr

I have 4 services, each has a method with the signature like this:

```
PortSet<Response1, Exception> GetData1(Request1 request);
PortSet<Response2, Exception> GetData2(Request2 request);
PortSet<Response3, Exception> GetData3(Request3 request);
PortSet<Response4, Exception> GetData4(Request4 request);
```

I need to run them concurrently and join the final result, processing result and exception that comes from each port separately. Could you please suggest how do I do this?

I was able to find only possibility to join the results from the Port's, not from PortSet's.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is somewhat limited by the number of classes involved. I'd suggest activating `Choice` receivers on each `PortSet`, and in each handler to `Post` to a completion port. On the completion port, you could use a `Join` when they all complete.So, off the top of my head, and assuming you are deriving from `CcrServiceBase` (otherwise you'll need to use `Arbiter.Activate` instead of the terser `Activate`):

```
var cPort=new Port<EmptyValue>();
Activate(GetData1(myRequest1)
    .Choice(r1=>{
        Process(r1);
        cPort.Post(EmptyValue.SharedInstance);
    },ex=>{
        Process(ex);
        cPort.Post(EmptyValue.SharedInstance);
    }); //etc 4 times

Activate(cPort.Join(4,e=>{
    //all completed. Proceed here...
}));
```

If instead you had a common `Response` type, you could instead structure your calls as follows:

```
var PortSet<Response,Exception> ps=new PortSet<Response,Exception>();
GetData1(request1,ps);
GetData2(request2,ps);
GetData3(request3,ps);
GetData4(request4,ps);
```

so instead of the `GetData` call creating a new `PortSet`, you provide a common `PortSet` and supply it to the `GetData` methods.

Now, you can perform a multiple item receive:

```
ps.MultipleItemReceive(4,
    responses=> {
        foreach(var response in responses)
        {
            //process response
        }
    },
    exceptions=> {
        foreach(var exception in exceptions)
        {
            //process exception
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, I'm somehow limited by the number of different responses I receive, and that's why I have asked this question :). Unfortunately, I have to stick to different results as they're coming from different sources (different even by nature, since several of them will perform web request, others will call a web service and some will go to a database). Thus, the first solution fits well for me, thanks!